# Plot smoothed average of third variable by x and y

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a 2D plot where the x and y axes are predictor variables. I would like to summarize a third variable smoothly as the counts at a particular coordinate are very low.

For example, I might want to plot the probability of default against assets and debt. This is similar to a density plot, but rather than plot the smoothed density of the observations, I want to plot an arbitrary smoothed value such as default rate.

I have tried using `stat_density_2d` in `ggplot2` but have not figured out how to make it summarize a third variable as the "density" instead of observation counts.

Sample data:

```
data(iris)
plt <- data.frame(iris[c(1,2)], y=as.numeric(iris$Species == "setosa"))
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plt, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill= ..density..), geom="tile", contour=FALSE)
```

[image]

But instead of the color representing the density of observations. I want it to represent a summarized variable. In this case, the probability that species == "setosa"

Comment: `ggplot2` is considered "software tools commonly used by programmers". At least `R` programmers.

Comment: Sounds like you want what most people would call a pseudo-3D plot. (And ggplot2 has historically not provided those.) If you post some sample data, we could use either base or lattice graphics to demonstrate.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide some example (fictitious) data and code. Also see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density_2d.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** Based on the [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134641/discussion-between-zelazny7-and-eipi10), it looks like you're referring to a two-dimensional kernel smoothing function. The [`smoothie` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smoothie/index.html) might have what you need.

Regardless of how you estimate the loan default probability (the variable that gets mapped to the fill color, which I've called `p.default` below) at a given (x,y) point (e.g., binned averages, logistic regression, kernel smoothing, etc.), you can create the plot with something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(assets, debt, fill=p.default)) + geom_tile()
```

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment, for the `iris` example, you'd need to average the y values over regions of `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` to get the average probability. These data are pretty sparse, so you'll need relatively large cells to get more than one observation per cell. Also, `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` fall in almost completely different regions for each species, so you'll still get all 1's or all 0's in almost all cells. In the example below, I just assign random values of 1 and 0 in order to get a mix of 1s and 0s in several cells.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(5)
plt <- data.frame(iris[c(1,2)], y=sample(0:1, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE))
```

In the code below, we use the `cut` function to cut `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` into 10 ranges each. Then we average the 1s and 0s in each cell to get the average of `y` for each cell. This average `y` value is then represented by the fill color gradient.

```
plt %>% group_by(Sepal.Length = cut(Sepal.Length, 10),
                 Sepal.Width = cut(Sepal.Width, 10)) %>%
  summarise(y=mean(y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, fill=y)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Or, we could fit a logistic regression model, which would give us predictions of `y` for any combination of `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width`:

```
# Logistic regression model
m1 = glm(y ~ poly(Sepal.Length,2)*poly(Sepal.Width,2), family="binomial", data=plt)

# Get predictions on a grid of values
df = expand.grid(Sepal.Length=seq(4,8,length=100), Sepal.Width=seq(2,5,length=100))
df$y.pred = predict(m1, newdata=df, type="response")

ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, fill=y.pred)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="yellow",high="red", midpoint=0.5,limits=c(0,1))
```

[image]

The general idea is that you need a single value (let's call it `z`) to associate with each (x,y) point on your graph. You can calculate those `z` values by averaging over regions in the (x,y) plane, with a model, etc. Once you have the `z` values that go with each (x,y) point, you can generate a tile plot where `z` is the `fill` aesthetic.

**Original Answer**

It sounds like maybe you want a heat map. The fill color would represent the value of the third variable, in this case probability of default. Perhaps something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Fake data
df = expand.grid(income=seq(1,1e5,length=100), debt=seq(1,5e5,length=100))
df$p.default = df$income - 0.3*df$debt
df$p.default = df$p.default - max(df$p.default)
df$p.default = abs(df$p.default)/max(abs(df$p.default))

ggplot(df, aes(income, debt, fill=p.default)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(0,1), low="blue", mid="yellow", high="red", midpoint=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: It's close, but the fill variable has to be a calculated field. I have a variable called default that takes on the values 1 and 0. I need to average them for values of x and y to create my fill color. But the average needs to be a weighted kernel average because there is often only one data point for the majority of unique x and y pairings.

Comment: Then you just need to calculate the average at each (x,y) pair by whatever method you're using. That calculated field then becomes your fill variable. If you provide a sample of your data (paste into your question the output of `dput(data_sample)`) and the method you want to use to calculate the average at each point, then we can provide a full solution.

Comment: You can see an example dataset with the `plt` object I create in my example. The `y` variable needs to be summarized by `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width`. However each unique pair of `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` usually only has one observation. Which makes the average always 0 or 1.

Comment: I appreciate all of the effort you're putting into the answer, and I will upvote as a result. But unfortunately I cannot use these solutions. A kernel density of the variable-to-be-summarized is what I think will work best. I am aware of the geom_tile solutions and it is too discrete. The model seems like a a good bet, but I am doing exploratory analysis and I need to see the true relationships, not a modeled one.

Comment: On the one hand, you say you want a kernel density estimate. But this is essentially a smoothed histogram (i.e., a count of the number of values at a given location or the fraction of all values that are found at a given location). On the other hand, you say that the data you want to plot is the estimated probability of default, given particular values for assets and debt. These are two different things. (continued in next comment)

Comment: The latter can be estimated in a number of ways (e.g., averages for given ranges of assets and debt, logistic regression, various machine learning methods, etc.). But these will give you a probability surface (the estimated probability of default, conditional on specific values for assets and debt), not counts or percentages. It seems like that's what you actually want. Please advise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134641/discussion-between-zelazny7-and-eipi10).